# Selenium - Collect info from every item in a list

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Sorry for the newbie question here, but I'm trying to learn web scraping by working on Yelp's Eat24.com site. I am able to 1) get the driver to eat24.com, 2)choose pickup, 3) search for a location, 4) click on the first menu and 5) collect the menu items. I'm unable, however, to go back to the original list of restaurants and choose the next menu in the list. Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

#go to eat24, type in zip code 10007, choose pickup and click search

driver.get("https://new-york.eat24hours.com/restaurants/index.php")
search_area = driver.find_element_by_name("address_auto_complete")
search_area.send_keys("10007")
pickup_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//[@id='search_form']/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]")
pickup_element.click()
search_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='search_form']/div/table/tbody/tr/td[3]/button")
search_button.click()


#scroll up and down on page to load more of 'infinity' list

for i in range(0,3):
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 
document.body.scrollHeight);")
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,0);")
    time.sleep(1)

#find menu buttons

menus_elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@title="View Menu"]')
#menus_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@title="View Menu"]')
#menus_element.click()

#Problem area: Trying to iterate over menu buttons and collect menu items + prices from each. It goes to the first menu and pulls the prices/menu items, but then when it goes back to first page it says 'stale element reference' and doesn't click the next menu item


for i in range(0, len(menus_elements)):
    if menus_elements[i].is_displayed():
        menus_elements[i].click()
 #find menu items
    menu_items = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("cpa")
    menus = [x.text for x in menu_items]
#find menu prices
    menu_prices = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('item_price')
    menu_prices = [x.text for x in menu_prices]
        #pair menu items and prices
    for menu, menu_price in zip(menus, menu_prices):
        print(menu + ': ' + menu_price)
    driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-1)")
    driver.implicitly_wait(20)
```

The problem is at the end here, it goes to the first menu and grabs the items/prices, but when it goes back a page, it doesn't select the second menu and do the same thing. Why? Thank you for any and all advice!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of clicking each "View menu" button, scraping menu page and getting back to result page you can get the list of links and then scrape each menu page one by one:

```
menu_urls = [page.get_attribute('href') for page in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@title="View Menu"]')]
for url in menu_urls:
    driver.get(url)
    menu_items = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("cpa")
    menus = [x.text for x in menu_items]
    ...
```